# Email stuck in outbox but can't access it

Tags: email, ms-office, error

I have Office 2011 installed on Mac OS 10.6 and I tried to send an email to multiple recipients and got this error: `The message could not be sent because it has unresolved recipients`. And now, every time it does Send/Receive I get this error: `A message could not be sent`

The problem is that the message got stuck in Outbox but I can't access it, can't delete it, nothing. Any idea how I could get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by deleting the account (it was an IMAP account) and exporting the emails (`File -> Export -> .olm`) and adding back the account.

Answer (score 2):

Open the **AppleScript Editor** found in /Applications/Utilities. 
Paste in the following three lines:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  delete every message of outbox
end tell
```

Click the **Run** button at the top and this should delete every message in your Outbox.